# Prevent react-native-router-flux from rendering all components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router

I'm using React-Native-Router-Flux for routing my app. The issue is that it seems like when a redux state changes, ALL the components under the Router gets rerendered, not just the "current" component.

So lets say I have 2 components under the Router: **Register** and **Login** and both share the same **authenticationReducer**. Whenever an authentication event (such as user registration or signin) fails, I want to display error Alerts.

The problem is that when an error is fired from one of the components, two Alerts show up at the same time, one from each component. I assumed when I am currently on the Register scene, only the error alert would show from the Register component.

However, it seems like both components rerender whenever the redux state changes, and I see 2 alerts (In the below example, both 'Error from REGISTER' and 'Error from SIGNIN').

Here are the components:

## main.ios.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <Scene key='root'>
                        <Scene key='register' component={Register} type='replace'>
                        <Scene key='signin' component={SignIn} type='replace'>
                    </Scene>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

## Register.js

```
class Register extends Component {
    render() { 
        const { loading, error } = this.props;
        if (!loading && error) {
            Alert.alert('Error from REGISTER');
        }

        return <View>...</View>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.get("authenticationReducer").get("loading"),
        error:   state.get("authenticationReducer").get("error"),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Register);
```

## SignIn.js

```
class SignIn extends Component {
    render() { 
        const { loading, error } = this.props;
        if (!loading && error) {
            Alert.alert('Error from SIGNIN');
        }

        return <View>...</View>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.get("authenticationReducer").get("loading"),
        error:   state.get("authenticationReducer").get("error"),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);
```

How do I change this so that only the REGISTER error message shows when I am currently on the Register Scene, and vice versa?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way react-native-router-flux works, all previous pages are still "open" and mounted. I am not totally sure if this solution will work, because of this weird quirk.

Pretty strict (and easy) rule to follow with React: No side-effects in render. Right now you are actually doing a side-effect there, namely, the Alert.alert(). Render can be called once, twice, whatever many times before actually rendering. This will, now, cause the alert to come up multiple times as well!

Try putting it in a componentDidUpdate, and compare it to the previous props to make sure it only happens once:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.error && this.props.error !== prevProps.error) {
    // Your alert code
  }
}
```

I am not totally convinced that this will actually work, as the component will still update because it is kept in memory by react-native-router-flux, but it will at least have less quirks.

Comment: Just call the pop function of the Action of the react router flux.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating an ErrorContainer to watch for errors and connected it to a component that uses [react-native-simple-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-modal) to render a single error modal throughout the app.

This approach is nice because you only need error logic and components defined once. The react-native-simple-modal component is awesomely simple to use too. I have an errors store that's an array that I can push errors to from anywhere. In the containers mapStateToProps I just grab the first error in the array (FIFO), so multiple error modals just "stack up", as you close one another will open if present.

container:

```
const mapStateToProps = (
  state ) => {
    return {
      error: state.errors.length > 0 ? state.errors[0] : false
    };
};
```

reducer:

```
export default function errors (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ERRORS.PUSH:
            return state.concat({
                type: action.errorType,
                message: action.message,
            });
        case actionTypes.ERRORS.POP:
            return state.slice(1);
        case actionTypes.ERRORS.FLUSH:
            return [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```